# Trying to implement a function to delete a struct in a linked list while assigning the struct before it to point to the struct after it

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I understand that there are better ways to do what I'm attempting, but this is a question in a book that I'm using to learn C++ and it will help me grasp some of the fundamentals before I move on. Anyway, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct EnemySpaceShip
{
    int weapon_power;
    int xcoord;
    int ycoord;
    EnemySpaceShip *nextEnemy;
};

EnemySpaceShip* getNewEnemy(EnemySpaceShip* p_enemies) // Creates a new EnemySpaceShip in linked list p_enemies
{
    EnemySpaceShip *p_ship = new EnemySpaceShip;
    p_ship->xcoord = 0;
    p_ship->ycoord = 0;
    p_ship->weapon_power = 10;
    p_ship->nextEnemy = p_enemies;
    p_enemies = p_ship;
    return p_ship;
}

EnemySpaceShip* findPreRemove(EnemySpaceShip* p_enemies, int x_attack, int y_attack) // finds the element that is before the ship to be removed or returns NULL
{
    EnemySpaceShip *p_current = p_enemies;
    EnemySpaceShip *initialShip = p_enemies;
    int i= 0;
    while (p_current != NULL)
    {
        i++;
        if (p_current->xcoord == x_attack && p_current->ycoord == y_attack)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                delete initialShip;
                delete p_current;
                return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < i - 1; j++)
                {
                    initialShip = initialShip->nextEnemy;
                }
                delete p_current;
                return initialShip;
            }
        }
        p_current = p_current->nextEnemy;
    }
    return NULL;
}

EnemySpaceShip* findRemove(EnemySpaceShip* p_enemies, int x_attack, int y_attack)
{
    EnemySpaceShip *p_current = p_enemies;
    while (p_current != NULL)
    {
        if (p_current->xcoord == x_attack && p_current->ycoord == y_attack)
        {
            return p_current;
        }
        p_current = p_current->nextEnemy;
    }
}

EnemySpaceShip* removeEnemyShip(EnemySpaceShip *p_ship) // deletes the ship parameter and returns the ship after it in the list
{
    EnemySpaceShip *enemyAfterRemove = new EnemySpaceShip;
    enemyAfterRemove = p_ship->nextEnemy;
    delete p_ship;
    return enemyAfterRemove;
}

int main()
{
    EnemySpaceShip *p_enemies = NULL;
    EnemySpaceShip *Ship1 = getNewEnemy(p_enemies);
    EnemySpaceShip *Ship2 = getNewEnemy(p_enemies);
    EnemySpaceShip *Ship3 = getNewEnemy(p_enemies);

    Ship3->xcoord = 5; //arbitrary numbers to test the code
    Ship3->ycoord = 5;

    EnemySpaceShip *ShipBeforeRemove = findPreRemove(p_enemies, 5, 5);
    EnemySpaceShip *ShipToRemove = findRemove(p_enemies, 5, 5);
    ShipBeforeRemove->nextEnemy = removeEnemyShip(ShipToRemove);
}
```

I'm using arbitrary values to test the program, I don't need to fully implement this as a functionality for the game that it is apparently being used for. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your structure only points forward, so you lose the 'ship before this one' -- keep a pointer like `p_last`. Unless you make it two-way (a pointer before and after) you can't delete an element with no prior context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope following is what you want.. Removing an element from a singly linked list..

```
EnemySpaceShip* removeFromList(EnemySpaceShip* p_enemies, int x_attack, int y_attack)
{
    if(p_enemies == NULL)
        return NULL;

    EnemySpaceShip *p1 = p_enemies;
    EnemySpaceShip *p2 = p1->next;

    if(p2 == NULL)
    {
        // Trivial case..

        if(p1->xcoord == x_attack && p1->ycoord == y_attack)
        {
            delete p_enemies;
            p_enemies = NULL;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    while(p2 != NULL)
    {
         if(p2->xcoord == x_attack && p2->ycoord == y_attack)
         {
             // Element found, remove it and assign its previous pointer
             // as the next pointer of the deleted one..
             p1->next = p2->next;
             delete p2;
             return p1;
         }
         else
         {
             p1 = p2;
             p2 = p2->next;
         }
    }

    return NULL;
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, the problem was for the function to just take the ship that was to be removed as a parameter. I think that the problem makes a situation that doesn't need to be so complicated and kind of misses the point of the exercise. The code that you linked is the more realistic way of doing it, and I think that I'm willing to just accept that and move on instead of dangling on the unimportant specifics of that question. Thanks a lot for your insight and time.